# While placing order in react.js with stripe getting error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

```
 const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        }
    }).then(({paymentIntent}) => {
        // paymentIntent = payment confirmation

        db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection('orders')
        .doc(paymentIntent.id)
        .set({
            basket: basket,
            amount: paymentIntent.amount,
            created: paymentIntent.created
        })

        setSucceeded(true)
        setError(null)
        setProcessing(false)

        dispatch({
            type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
        })

        history.replace('/orders')
    })
}
```

below is the error iam getting
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at payment.js:58:1
at async handleSubmit (payment.js:51:1)

Answer (score 0):

Can you print out your `paymentIntent` variable to see if you're actually getting the PaymentIntent back successfully? Likely that's not succeeding which causes `paymentIntent` variable to be `undefined` when you try to grab the `id` from it.